# Getting form data in QtWebEnginePage

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm updating an old app from Qt 4.8 which was more or less a glorified scraper.  I used QWebView::QWebElementCollection to get forms and their inputs.  Is there nothing of the sort in QWebEnginePage?  That was a very handy feature.  I read in the docs that it's deprecated, and why, but I fail to see how there couldn't be some similar functionality.

Comment: QtWebEngine runs all the web content in a separate process, so it wouldn't be practical to have synchronous communication between the main process and the web process for most use cases.